# AndEngineRuntimeException: Inherently incompatible device detected.

Tags: android, andengine

I am getting error like this on my phone when i run my AndEngine program
it is successfully run on my frnds phone but when i tried to run i am getting error like Inherently incompatible device detected...

my logcat is below

```
   10-16 14:13:23.061: E/AndroidRuntime(4533): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 10
   10-16 14:13:23.061: E/AndroidRuntime(4533): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
   10-16 14:13:23.061: E/AndroidRuntime(4533):  at org.andengine.opengl.vbo.attribute.VertexBufferObjectAttributeFix.glVertexAttribPointer(VertexBufferObjectAttributeFix.java:39)
   10-16 14:13:23.061: E/AndroidRuntime(4533):  at org.andengine.opengl.vbo.attribute.VertexBufferObjectAttributes.glVertexAttribPointers(VertexBufferObjectAttributes.java:50)
   10-16 14:13:23.061: E/AndroidRuntime(4533):  at org.andengine.opengl.shader.ShaderProgram.bind(ShaderProgram.java:126)
   10-16 14:13:23.061: E/AndroidRuntime(4533):  at org.andengine.opengl.shader.PositionTextureCoordinatesShaderProgram.bind(PositionTextureCoordinatesShaderProgram.java:86)
   10-16 14:13:23.061: E/AndroidRuntime(4533):  at org.andengine.opengl.vbo.VertexBufferObject.bind(VertexBufferObject.java:162)
   10-16 14:13:23.061: E/AndroidRuntime(4533):  at org.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureWarmUpVertexBufferObject.warmup(TextureWarmUpVertexBufferObject.java:97)
   10-16 14:13:23.061: E/AndroidRuntime(4533):  at org.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureManager.updateTextures(TextureManager.java:257)
   10-16 14:13:23.061: E/AndroidRuntime(4533):  at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onDrawFrame(Engine.java:613)
   10-16 14:13:23.061: E/AndroidRuntime(4533):  at org.andengine.opengl.view.EngineRenderer.onDrawFrame(EngineRenderer.java:105)
   10-16 14:13:23.061: E/AndroidRuntime(4533):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1332)
   10-16 14:13:23.061: E/AndroidRuntime(4533):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1116)
   10-16 14:13:23.061: E/AndroidRuntime(4533): Caused by: org.andengine.util.exception.AndEngineRuntimeException: Inherently incompatible device detected.
   10-16 14:13:23.061: E/AndroidRuntime(4533):  at org.andengine.opengl.GLES20Fix.<clinit>(GLES20Fix.java:39)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As is [stated here by 42labs](http://42labs.tumblr.com/post/23674161190/fixing-crash-in-andengines-live-wallpaper-on-2-2):

> Luckily it is very easy to fix - in your sources root (the directory
>   where AndroidManifest.xml is) make a directory named libs inside which
>   then make a directory named armeabi. Now get AndEnginesources (from an
>   OpenGL ES 2.0 branch) - [from here](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine). You can clone the repository
>   or download it. Doesn’t matter.
>
> **What matters is that you should copy the libandengine.so available there in libs/armeabi to the libs/armeabi you have just created in
>   your directory. Will fix the issue :)**
>
> Probably this is not the official solution, maybe we haven’t seen a
>   note somewhere on AndEngine’s forums, but this method fixes the
>   problem in 30 seconds and doesn’t produce any other issues.
>
> And - Why did it crash? What does it fix?
>
> It’s quite funny actually. Google developers, when preparing the Froyo
>   Java SDK, forgot to implement Java versions of some of (standard!)
>   OpenGL ES 2.0 functions. The solution to this problem is to use JNI to
>   create a call bridge to a native function that is missing in the SDK.
>   AndEngine has this bridge in the mentioned libandengine.so. When the
>   engine is launched it checks the version of OS. If it is Froyo (or
>   lower) it tries to load the library. If the library is not present it
>   has no way of solving this and has to crash.